# Is there a way to sheathe a weapon faster than a move action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, actions

There are a couple ways that you can draw weapons as a free action, but I am unable to locate any core rules which allow you to sheathe weapons as other than a move action.

There is *Path of War*'s [Improved Quick Draw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/improved-quick-draw-combat/) feat, which allows you to draw and sheath as part of an AOO.

There is the 3rd-party feat [Quick Sheath](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/flaming-crab-games/combat-feats-3rd-party-flaming-crab-games/quick-sheath-combat/).

But there are no magic items or feats that characters can take to obtain this ability. Have I missed a source somewhere or is there nothing?

Comment: Is there a reason to *need* to sheath it or does it just make you feel bad when you throw on the floor your *+5 brilliant energy keen spiked chain*?

Comment: I have a summoned whos fused with the Eidolon. I have multiple arms and each arm has a weapon, but when i want to cast, I need a free hand, and I dont want to keep dropping weapons to cast

Comment: Also, it lets me keep my weapons the same size when under the effects of enlarge person.

Comment: The answers point to many different feats, leading me to believe there is no chance to an ultimate and complete answer.

Comment: The question (wisely) does not ask for *all* ways to do this, and I believe it is thus not too broad.

Comment: Even if the question asked for *all* ways, if the answer can be resumed in a list of less than 10 items, then it isn't too broad at all.

Answer (score 8):

[Gloves of Storing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/glove-of-storing/): Storing or retrieving an item that can be held in one hand and weighs < 20 pounds as a free action.

[Gun Twirling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/grit-feats/gun-twirling-grit/): As long as you have 1 grit point, holster a one-handed firearm as a free action.

[Quick Draw + Combat Trick](http://archivesofnethys.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Quick%20Draw): As long as you have 1 stamina point in your stamina pool, you can sheathe a weapon as a swift action. [Stamina](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/stamina-and-combat-tricks-optional-rules/) is an optional rule system, so needs GM/group OK to introduce.

[Quickdraw Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/quickdraw-shield/): Swift action to put away combined with a regular move, if you have Quick Draw, put it away as a free action. Included because it could be considered a weapon if you bash with it.

There's also 2 levels in the [Bard's Juggler Archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/juggler-bard-archetype/) for **Combat Juggling (Ex)**. While not sheathing, so long as you are juggling fewer than 3 objects, the hand is considered free for things like somatic components. (This is based on the comment about needing this to cast spells as a summoner without always dropping everything).

Answer (score 5):

[Scabbard of Many Blades](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/scabbard-of-many-blades/) (5000 gp) plus Quickdraw lets you sheathe one weapon and draw another, as a single swift action.

[Blink Back Belt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-blink-back/) (5000 gp) automatically retrieves and sheathes your thrown weapons (but *only* thrown weapons).

[Mixed Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/mixed-combat-combat/) is another Path of War feat (also printed in Ultimate Psionics, and a class-feature of [Bushi archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/classes/martial-class-templates/bushi-template/)), which lets you sheathe as a free action. It's not restricted to AOOs, unlike Improved Quick Draw.

[Signature Skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/signature-skill-general/) / [Rogue's Edge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/#TOC-Rogue-s-Edge-Ex-): [Sleight of Hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/sleight-of-hand#TOC-Sleight-of-Hand-Unchained) with 15 skill ranks lets you draw or sheathe a hidden weapon as a swift action.

[Phantom Sun Stance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/solar-wind-maneuvers/#TOC-Phantom-Sun-Stance) (Path of War, Solar Wind discipline) lets you draw a temporary copy of a thrown weapon, while leaving the original in your sheath. Unlike Blink Back Belt, you don't have to actually throw it; you could pick a dagger or spear or anything else that's usable both as thrown and melee.

[Spiritbound item quirk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Quirks) might or might not work. A generous interpretation might have it teleport back to your sheath whenever you drop it, and/or just be in your sheath whenever you want to draw it. But RAW doesn't specify on the granularity of action economy.

[-2 Cursed Sword](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/#TOC-Sword-2-Cursed) might or might not work. It's unclear whether it literally teleports to your hand when you try to draw something else, in which case you can drop the sword as a free action and then "draw" it from the floor as easily as you could draw something from your belt; or whether it's merely a mental compulsion that never expands your options.

Answer (score 5):

[Quick Stow](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Quick%20Stow) could be that you seek. It allow you to sheath weapons and [Quick Draw](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Quick%20Draw) in the same move action, and it also work with the [Two-Weapon Fighting](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Two-Weapon%20Fighting) feat. Meaning that you could fire with a Bow, and then move into melee sheathing the Bow and drawing two Short Swords in the same round.