# Can drawing a weapon be part of any kind of move action, or just part of movement?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, weapons, two-weapon-fighting, move-action

Assuming a character has a BAB higher than +1, would he be able to draw a weapon (or shield) as a move action and then draw (or sheath) another weapon (or shield) as part of that same move action (due to his BAB)?

This question could be applied to any other move action; does it have to be specifically about moving the character, or could a character draw a weapon even while mounting a horse or picking up an object?

What about the Two-Weapon Fighting feat? Does that allow for drawing two weapons (or shields) as part of any move action, like standing up from prone (still with BAB higher than +1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you have a base attack bonus of +1 or higher, you may draw a weapon as a free action combined with a regular move.

<sup>([Draw or Sheathe a Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#Draw_or_Sheathe_a_Weapon))</sup>

The wording could be clearer, but “a regular move” refers to the action-in-combat “[Move](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#Move),” that is, using a move action to actually move your speed. You cannot draw a weapon while taking some other move action.

Answer (score 5):

A creature that possesses a base attack bonus of +1 or more "may draw a weapon as a free action combined with a regular move" (see [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Draw-or-Sheathe-a-Weapon)). Although the game never says it outright, this reader and everyone he's played with has always assumed that a regular move means "[t]he simplest move action[, i.e.] moving your speed" (see [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Move)).

Further, "If you have the Two-Weapon Fighting feat, you can draw two light or one-handed weapons in the time it would normally take you to draw one," and that includes during a regular move (see Note 3 [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#Table-Actions-in-Combat)).

Thus, unless the GM rules otherwise, a weapon (or sometimes two weapons) can be drawn when a creature that possesses a base attack bonus of +1 or more takes a move action to move up to its speed. Other move actions typically don't allow the simultaneous drawing of a weapon.

Also, *sheathing* a weapon shouldn't be conflated with *drawing* a weapon. It's actually much more difficult to sheathe a weapon quickly than to draw one. (See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109843/8610).) The two actions are entirely separate and unique actions with their own costs. A creature that possesses a base attack bonus of +1 or higher that takes a move action to move typically can't simultaneously sheathe its weapon, for example.